# Issues with python and the serverless framework

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to understand how to setup multiple python lambdas and a step function within one single `serverless.yml` with each python lambda having its own dependencies.  All of my lambda functions collaborate in the context of a step function for a shared common goal.  With this rationale, it makes sense to me to put all of the code under one `serverless.yml` file.
As part of my MANY hours of trial and error and reading I found about the `serverless-python-requirements` plugin for `The Serverless Framework` that helps in packaging python functions that rely on OS-specific python libraries and also allow the separation of multiple `requirements.txt` in case different lambdas require different dependencies.
So at this point my problem is that the generated package is not including the dependencies that I provide in the requirements.txt whenever each function has its own requirements.txt

These are my artifacts:

### package.json

```
    {
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "serverless-python-requirements": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless": "^1.72.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

### serverless.yml

```
service: example

frameworkVersion: ">=1.72.0 <2.0.0"

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  stage: "${opt:stage, env:SLS_STAGE, 'local'}"
  log_level: "${env:LOG_LEVEL, 'INFO'}"
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true

provider:
  name: aws
  # profile: ${self:custom.profile}
  stage: ${self:custom.stage}
  runtime: python3.8
  environment:
    LOG_LEVEL: ${self:custom.log_level}

package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - vendored/**

functions:
  function1:
    # module: folder1
    handler: folder1/function1.handler
    package:
      include:
        - 'folder1/**'
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 60
  function2:
    # module: folder2
    handler: folder2/function2.handler
    package:
      include:
        - 'folder2/**'
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 60
```

finally, my 2 python lambda functions are in separate folders and one of them requires specific dependencies:

- folder1

  - function1.py
  - requirements.txt
- folder2

  - function1.py

### function1.py

```py
import json
import logging
import os
import sys
import pyjokes

log_level = os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO')
logging.root.setLevel(logging.getLevelName(log_level))
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class HandlerBaseError(Exception):
    '''Base error class'''

class ComponentIdentifierBaseError(HandlerBaseError):
    '''Base Component Identifier Error'''

def handler(event, context):
    '''Function entry'''
    _logger.debug('Event received: {}'.format(json.dumps(event)))

    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "joke":pyjokes.get_joke()
    }

    resp = {
        'status': 'OK',
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    _logger.debug('Response: {}'.format(json.dumps(resp)))
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler('', '')
```

### requirements.txt

```
pyjokes==0.6.0
```

### function2.py

```py
import json
import logging
import os
import sys

log_level = os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO')
logging.root.setLevel(logging.getLevelName(log_level))
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class HandlerBaseError(Exception):
    '''Base error class'''

class ElasticSearchPopulatorBaseError(HandlerBaseError):
    '''Base Component Identifier Error'''

def handler(event, context):
    '''Function entry'''
    _logger.debug('Event received: {}'.format(json.dumps(event)))

    resp = {
        'status': 'OK'
    }


    _logger.debug('Response: {}'.format(json.dumps(resp)))
    return resp
```

*Note:  I did try using the module+handler keywords in the `serverless.xml` as recommended on this link:  ttps://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements without any success*

Something that I noted is that if I use the module+handler as follows:

```
functions:
  function1:
    module: folder1
    handler: function1.handler
    package:
      include:
        - 'folder1/**'
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 60
```

Then, when I try running the function locally using:  `serverless invoke local -f function1 --log` I get an error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'function1'
```

Also, if anyone has an example of multiple lambdas with different `requirements.txt` that works I would be very gratelful, ideally something just different than the typical hello world examples, the hello worlds all work very well for me ;), but in scenarios like this one where I would like to setup common libraries, have different dependencies, etc, and use one common serverless.yml things seem to fall apart.  Again, my opinion is that these lambdas will operate together under one step function umbrella so there's strong cohesion here and I think that their build and deployment should happen under one common serverless service.

Comment: Are you using venv for this set up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently developed a similar application using the `serverless-python-requirements` plugin that encapsulates multiple lambdas as part of one stack, and I was receiving `ModuleNotFoundError` whilst invoking the lambda function locally, yet it would work remotely; however, when I removed the `module` parameter from my `serverless.yml` file I was able to invoke locally but then it broke for remote executions.

I've been able to find a workaround by setting a path prefix in my `serverless.yml`:

```yaml
functions:
  LambdaTest:
    handler: ${env:HANDLER_PATH_PREFIX, ""}handler.handler
    module: src/test_lambda
    package:
      include:
        - src/test_lambda/**
```

When I invoke the function locally, I prepend the environment variable to my command:

```sh
HANDLER_PATH_PREFIX=src/test_lambda/ ./node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js invoke local -f LambdaTest -p ./tests/resources/base_event.yml
```

I don't include the environment variable when invoking the function in AWS.

In order for this to work, I needed to add an **init**.py file to the root directory where my lambda function resides with the following code (taken from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375740/3633298)) so that any modules I'm including in the code that exist in the lambda's directory (e.g. `some_module` -- see directory tree below):

```py
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

My lambda's directory structure:

```
src/
└── test_lambda
    ├── __init__.py <=== add the code to this one
    ├── handler.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── some_module
        ├── __init__.py
        └── example.py
```

As for your question regarding lambdas that use different `requirements.txt` files -- I use the `individually` parameter, like so:

```yaml
package:
  individually: true
  include:
    - infra/**
  exclude:
    - "**/*"
```

Within each `requirements.txt` for each lambda I refer to a separate `requirements.txt` file that resides in the base directory of my project using the `-r` option -- this file contains libraries that are common to all lambdas, so when Serverless is installing packages for each lambda it'll also include packages included in my `./requirements.txt` file too.

I've included this solution in an issue regarding the `serverless-python-requirements` plugin [in GitHub](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/520) which would be worth keeping an eye on should this behaviour of the `module` parameter turns out to be a bug.

Hope it helps and let me know if you require clarification on anything.

Comment: Appreciate it @sndrsnk, your workaround works for now, thanks a lot!